# How classloader loads and unloads static classes?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I'm writing a plugin to 3-rd party server application.
I'd like to know how usually java classloaders reload static classes?

Could anyone suggest a good doc that explains java classloading in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members of classes are not reloaded. (I assume you are not talking about static inner classes)

Instead static members are unloaded when a classloader is unloaded.  When a new classloader is loaded (with the same or similar code) static members are lazy loaded.